# git post-commit hook not executed

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm trying to implement a way to include `git` commit data into a LaTex document using the method described [here](http://thorehusfeldt.net/2011/05/13/including-git-revision-identifiers-in-latex/).

The hook looks like this:

```
$ cat post-commit 
#!/bin/sh

cd ../..

git log -1 --format="format:\
                \\gdef\\GITAbrHash{%h}\
                \\gdef\\GITHash{%H}\
                \\gdef\\GITAuthorDate{%ad}\
                \\gdef\\GITAuthorName{%an}" >> git.tex
```

When I do `chmod a+x post-commit` and then `./post-commit`, the file is generated appropriately. However, when I actually make a commit, the hook is not executed. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is that you `cd ../..` in order to navigate to your sources.

Try to replace the `cd ../..` with a `pushd ../..`. After calling `git log`, restore the directory with `popd`

---

**Apart of this:** I doubt that a post-commit hook is what you want here: if you did a successful commit, `git.tex` will be changed afterwards and you have a modified file.

A **pre-commit hook** would be a better choice: right before the commit is made, the hook gets called, modifies `git.tex` and then adds it to the commit.

Another option would be to have a *smudge* and *clean* filter for your `git.tex` file (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion). Every time you're going to do something like a release, just do a

```
git add git.tex
```

This will invoke the *clean* filter which generates the content of `git.tex`. This content will be sent to the repo. The *smudge* filter will be run when the file gets checked out. It's duty is to make the file empty, so it's just

```
echo '' > git.tex
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but that wasn't it; see my edit.

Comment: your edit would better be an answer to your own question instead of an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't need to do `cd ../..` because the code is executed in the root  directory of the repository anyway. The other mistake was `>> git.tex`, which of course should read `> git.tex`.